# SQL query error - "Column cannot be null"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, mysql

I have a SQL query:

```
String S = Editor1.Content.ToString(); 
     Response.Write(S);    
    string sql = "insert into testcase.ishan(nmae,orders) VALUES ('9',@S)"; 
   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S", S);  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> Error: Column 'orders' cannot be null at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError

Comment: i already have value in the string.but it is not geting into sql query

Comment: Is the column name truly _nmae_ or is it actually _name_ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters.aspx):

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
> ```
>
> The order in which OdbcParameter objects are added to the OdbcParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Use this:

```
string sql = "insert into testcase.ishan(nmae,orders) VALUES ('9', ?)";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("you_can_write_anything_here_its_ignored_anyway", S);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: and how to define value for '?'. how will query know what is ?

Comment: @user: add a parameter to the collection. It will know from the order it was added: the first parameter added is the first `?`, etc. It's in the quote I copied.

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful to you

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@S", OdbcType.Char, S);
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameterCollection.Add(string, System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType, int)' has some invalid arguments