# ODBC connection to MySQL won't add values

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, ado.net, odbc

I'm trying to insert values from my asp.net application into my MySQL database.

On the register page people can fill in `Name` and `Pass` and press submit.

```
Public Function InsertMember(ByVal objMember As Member) As Boolean

    myconn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO member(Name, Pass) VALUES (@Name,@Pass)", myconn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = objMember.Name
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Pass", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = objMember.Pass

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.Dispose()
    cmd = Nothing

    myconn.Close()
    myconn.Dispose()

    Return True

End Function
```

But all this does is add NULL values into my database.

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about switching convention to use `?` and parameter names matching the column names? 
Perhaps consider switching to [`AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) if you can.

From the [MSDN `OdbcParameterCollection.Add` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxdcah9t.aspx)

```
Dim insertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO member(Name, Pass) VALUES (?,?)"
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(insertSQL, myconn)
'cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = objMember.Name '

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", objMember.Name)           
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pass", objMember.Pass) 

'Note that with ODBC Command, the ORDER you add to the parameters collection
'matters most. The names of your params don't matter.
```

I suspect the `?` placeholders will be filled with the values **in order** as they're added to the Parameters collection (from [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042002/sql-query-error/4042059#4042059)).

Comment: just tried it, but doesn't change a thing, nothing gets added.

Comment: for sure :) when i debug just before executequery, i see which values should be added. And yes connection string is right, because a row gets added and all the values contain NULL

Comment: well I can see the values of objMember.Name and objMember.Pass?

Comment: hmmm I think i'm looking at the wrong thing? When I open up cmd or cmd.Parameters I see something different like: Count, IsFixedSize, Item, Item, ...

Comment: Confirm that if you hardcode a value like "INSERT INTO .... VALUES ('foo', 'bar')" , that the insert works properly?

Comment: when I look at Item it says "In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly  supplied by the user" I'll try to add parameters in the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an article that should solve your problem.  Basically, replace the @ characters with ? characters instead.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1283161.aspx

The OP in that forum was having problems with null values being inserted just like you.  The solution was to modify the code like so:

```
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO member(Name, Pass) VALUES (?Name,?Pass)", myconn)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Name", objMember.Name)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Pass", objMember.Pass)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you want to specify the value type for the field, you can do it like you had but you should add the length afterwards like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Name", OdbcType.VarChar, 30).Value = objMember.Name
```

I hope that helps.