# Execute a Stored Procedure using ODBC with Parameters

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using ODBC which has a parameter, but each time I do I get the following:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'aaPRO_CloseCall' expects parameter '@FaultID', which was not supplied.

My code is:

```
Dim I As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(LogIDTextBox.Text)
Dim ConnString As String = "Dsn=Test"
Dim Conn As Odbc.OdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConnString)
Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("aaPRO_closecall", Conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultID", I)
Conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Conn.Close()
```

I'm new to Visual Studio and I can't see what I've got wrong. I'd be very grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use `@name`s with ODBC, only question marks. See [ODBC connection to MySQL won't add values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002834/odbc-connection-to-mysql-wont-add-values).

Comment: How is the stored procedure defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in the end

```
         'Create the ODBC connection
        Dim Conn As Odbc.OdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConnString)
        Conn.Open()

        'Add the call to the stored procedure including the connection
        Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("{ CALL aaPRO_closecall(?) }", Conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'add the parameter to the stored procedure
        Dim MyParm As OdbcParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@FaultID", OdbcType.Int)
        MyParm.Value = FL

        'Execute the procedure
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'clean up after
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For more info see here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)